# SSRS: Using a control to switch between reports

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report with a tablix and I'd like to add a chart to it.  But what I want is a toggle that could switch between the tablix and the chart.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of options I can think of:

**1 Parameter based**

Add a **Chart** and a **Tablix** to the report, and a **Parameter** (I called mine `ShowItem`). Set the `Hidden` property for the two items based on the parameter, e.g. something like:

```
=IIf(Parameters!ShowItem.Value = "Tablix", false, true)
```

or

```
=IIf(Parameters!ShowItem.Value = "Chart", false, true)
```

The report will load the item based on the parameter. You can update the parameter and reload the report to switch items.

**2 Toggle Item**

Create a **TextBox**; I called mine `ToggleTextBox`. Set the `Hidden` property for one item to `True` and the other to `False`, then set both items to have the `ToggleItem` property set to `ToggleTextBox`.

You can click the **TextBox** to show/hide the two items.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I shall give the toggle option a try!  Thanks!

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Thanks for the info!

Comment: You're welcome. If you find an answer helpful, please consider upvoting and/or setting it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks, the Parameter-based option works nicely, though I anticipate the toggle (obviously only for choices between exactly two reports) will be nicer when I get a chance to try it.

Comment: Update: Yeah, the toggle works, and it's actually nicer in appropriate cases because the reload is quicker; a parameter seems to reload everything, whereas a toggle is faster and probably only affects the relevant 'blocks'

Comment: @IanPreston toggle works perfectly. Is there a way to change the text in the textbox when you toggle the reports?